# vimeo-unity-sdk: How do I replace an existing video?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vimeo

I manage to upload a new video to Vimeo from Unity, but I don't know how to replace the file of an existing video.

Here are the bricks I have so far:

- I have a reference to a VimeoRecorder component in my script
- My videorecorder is connected to an AVPro recorder
- I get the existing videos using a temp VimeoApi component
- And I trigger AVPro capture via public interface

In the current code I don't do anything special upon finding existing videos with same name, and the upload just creates a new video with the same name. No implicit replacement...

Code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using RenderHeads.Media.AVProMovieCapture;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Vimeo.Recorder;
using Vimeo;

public class CaptureProxy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public VimeoRecorder m_vimeoRecorder;
    VimeoApi m_vimeoApi;
    public CaptureBase m_movieCapture;

    void Start()
    {        
            m_movieCapture = gameObject.AddComponent<CaptureFromTexture>();
            m_movieCapture._isRealTime = false;
            m_movieCapture._manualUpdate = true;
            m_movieCapture._useMediaFoundationH264 = true;
            m_movieCapture._postCaptureSettings.writeFastStartStreamingForMp4 = true;    
            m_vimeoRecorder.avproEncoder = m_movieCapture;

        m_vimeoApi = gameObject.AddComponent<VimeoApi>();
        m_vimeoApi.token = m_vimeoRecorder.GetVimeoToken();
        m_vimeoApi.OnRequestComplete += VimeoGetVideosComplete;
        m_vimeoApi.OnError += OnVimeoRequestError;
        m_vimeoApi.GetVideosInFolder(m_vimeoRecorder.currentFolder);
    }

    private void VimeoGetVideosComplete(string response)
    {
        m_vimeoApi.OnRequestComplete -= VimeoGetVideosComplete;
        m_vimeoApi.OnError -= OnVimeoRequestError;
        Destroy(m_vimeoApi);

        var json = Vimeo.SimpleJSON.JSONNode.Parse(response);
        Vimeo.SimpleJSON.JSONNode videoData = json["data"];

        if (videoData.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < videoData.Count; i++)
            {
                VimeoVideo video = new VimeoVideo(videoData[i]);
                if (video.name.StartsWith(m_recordParams.filetag))
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Video already exists at url: " + video.uri);
                    // And that's what I know so far
                    // I would like to give the VimeoVideo object to m_videoRecorder for it to upload the video file to the same entry
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void StartCapture()
    {
        // starts the capture
        m_movieCapture.StartCapture();

    }

    public void StopCapture()
    {
        // stops the capture, and triggers Vimeo upload
        m_movieCapture.StopCapture();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Vimeo Unity SDK doesn't currently support video file replacement. However, this functionality is available in Vimeo's API. While logged into your Vimeo account, [visit this page](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#replacing-a-source-file) to learn how you could modify the Unity SDK to replace a Vimeo video.

Also feel free to file a [feature request on Github](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks Casey! I filed a feature request:
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues/55